# シェルスクリプトのcase文の評価について教えてください。

Tags: bash, sh, shellscript

シェル初心者です。
↓の本を参考に勉強をしていたのですが、caseの評価で気になるところが出てきたので
質問させてください。コードも↓の本から抜粋しています。
[技術評論社　-　［改訂新版］シェルスクリプト基本リファレンス](http://gihyo.jp/magazine/wdpress/plus/978-4-7741-4643-0)

```
case `uname -s` in
 Linux)
 echo 'OSはLinuxです'
 ;;
 FreeBSD)
 echo 'OSはFreeBSDです'
 ;; 
 Solaris)
 echo 'OSはSolarisです'
 ;; 
 *) 
 echo 'その他のOSです'
 ;;
esac
```

という処理なのですが、

```
uname -s
```

というコマンドはパターンが実行されるたびに実行される認識は正しいでしょうか？
重い処理をcase文の文字列に入れるとパフォーマンスが劣化してしまうのではないかと懸念しております。

また、比較はif文同様testコマンドで実行される認識はあってますでしょうか？

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらお手数をおかけしますがご教授頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `case` は operand を１回だけ評価します。
2. 各パターンを指定された順番に shell-glob 規則に基づいて operand と一致するかを試します。
3. パターン一致時 `;;` に至ったら `esac` に行きます（終了です）
4. パターン一致時 `;;&` に至ったら次のパターンをさらに評価しに行きます

ということで

```
case abc in
a*)
     echo match to a-asterisk
     ;;&
b)
     echo match to b
     ;;
abc)
     echo match to abc
     ;;
esac
```

は２つマッチします（どれにマッチするか考えてください）。
マッチパターンは shell-glob であって regexp ではないため `^a*` とかしてもマッチしません。

っと。
上記 `;;&` は最近の [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) 拡張機能であって、古い [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) および [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) では使えません。

Answer (score 6):

`uname -s` が実行されるのは一回だけです。

```
$ strace -f sh -c 'case `uname -s` in x) ;; y) ;; esac' 2>&1|grep 'exec[^ ]*uname'
[pid  4662] execve("/bin/uname", ["uname", "-s"], [/* 73 vars */]) = 0
```

`test` コマンドは利用しません。シェルの内部コマンドとして実行されます。なお、私の知る限り、世の中の sh とその派生シェルの `test` コマンド (`[` コマンド)もシェルの内部コマンドです。

また、`if` 文は必ず `test` コマンドが実行されるものではありません。`if` の後に記述した任意のコマンドラインの終了コードで判定しているだけです。

Comment: 本題とは関係がないのですが、`strace -e execve -f ... | grep uname` としてもよろしいかと(親(`sh`)と子(`/bin/uname`)が表示されますけれども)。

Comment: Linux であれば `exec*` という名前のシステムコールは `execve` しか存在しないようなので、それでも構わないです。ほかの OS では `execlp` などがあったりするので、どれが利用されるのかわからないので、明示的に列挙するよりは `exec` で `grep` するほうが簡単かと思い、回答のようにしました。(strace でなく truss だったりしますが)