# testコマンドの文字列比較条件式で'=='は許容されているのか？

Tags: bash, shellscript, sh

細かい話ですが、testコマンドの文字列比較で、

```
$ test "${hoge}" = 'aaa'
```

のように、`=`で一致しているかを評価するという説明は
Manpageに載っています。一方で、

```
$ test "${hoge}" == 'aaa'
```

でも一致しているかを評価できるという説明が見当たりません。
試してみると一致しているか評価できているので、
使えると思うのですが、何か推奨されていない理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: bash の man page には `The = operator is equivalent to ==. `, `string1 == string2, string1 = string2: True if the strings are equal. = should be used with the test command for POSIX conformance.` と記載されています。

Comment: ご回答してくださった方、ありがとうございました。確かにbashのmanpageの「条件式」の項に記載がありました。bashの拡張機能だったとは勉強になりました。ポータビリティーは意識していないのですが、'='を使おうと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

オイラんちにある HP-UX 11.11 の `/bin/sh` 上では

```
$ test a = a && echo yes
yes
$ test a == a && echo yes
sh: ==: A test parameter is not valid.
```

となりました。一方でその HP-UX 11.11 上の bash 4.3.30 では `test a == a` は動作します。

`bash-4.3.30/test.c` にも `bash-4.3.30/doc/bash.info` にも
`==` は `=` と同様文字列の等値比較であると書かれています。
POSIX 適合性を取るなら `=` を使え、とありますね。
`==` は `bash` の拡張機能でしょう。

`bash` は他にも拡張機能があるので POSIX 適合性優先なら注意する必要がありそうです。
[シェルスクリプトのcase文の評価について教えてください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14900/)